# How to run sqldeveloper in Linux?

Tags: sqldeveloper

```
Oracle SQL Developer  
Copyright (c) 1997, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /home/reza/.sqldeveloper/4.1.0/product.conf
```

[image]

Comment: Enter the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /home/oracle/.sqldeveloper/4.1.5/product.con

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not have root access and directory access root I did was right after giving root access

Comment: Thank you . It worked for me. I just had given 755 and it opened :)

Answer (score 1):

You can ask to your terminal where is your local copy of sql developer:

`whereis sqldeveloper`

go to this folder: (e.g.)

`cd /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper`

and run the executable file:

`./sqldeveloper &`